# Referencing "this" and attempting to store into a variable yields undefined but is defined in DevTools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, jsx

I'm seeing some odd behavior in my React app regarding the bound "this" - I have a function that's part of a component called "App".  It is in a separate file, which I've bound the "this" command to from the main file.

I'm noticing that within the function itself the behavior of "this" is inconsistent.  As you can see in the code example below, when referencing "this" with regards to the first few variables before the conditional I'm seeing it bind correctly in the debugger, But when I reference either the bound variable or the "this" statement in the conditional I'm getting undefined values.  From what I understand, conditionals don't change the scope of "this" like functions do, so it makes no sense what the issue is.

**Edit: updated with exact code for clarity**

Undo.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {App} from 'react';

export default function onUndoAction(event){

    //Need to prevent error throw on undefined 

  let undoArrLength = this.state.undo.length-1;
      let undoType = this.state.undo[undoArrLength].type;


  //undoType.check is only present in undo events with cell value entries

  let undoStateCopyOut = this.state;

  if (undoType == "cell"){

    let undoStateCopy = this.state;


    //loop back to prior similar undo action

    for(let i = undoStateCopy.length-2; i >= 0; i--){
      if(undoStateCopy[i].type == "cell"){
        //Set this value as the new value 
        this.setState({gridState: undoStateCopy[i]})
        //then pop the prior value
        /*  Need to integrate this. 
        let addition = newUndo.pop();
        newRedo.push();
        let newRedo = redoStateCopy.splice(redoStateCopy.length-1,0, newUndo);
        this.setState({undo: newUndo});
        this.setState({redo: newRedo});
        */
        break;
      }
    }

  }
    ... additional code
```

Main.js

```
...

      onUndoAction(){
        onUndoAction;
      }


...skipping to render method

render(){
        return (
          <div>
          <table>
          <tbody onLoad = {this.broadcast()}>  
            {this.MainTableGet()}
          </tbody>
          </table>
          <ButtonMenu onRow = {this.onRowButton} onCol = {this.onColumnButton} undo ={ (e) => this.onUndoAction(e)} redo = {this.onRedoAction} reset = {this.onResetAction} />
          </div>

        );
      }
```

A few things to note:

I'm not sure if this is an idiosyncratic issue with React- I know you can't use conditionals within JSX, and technically this is a function that is referenced to in a render function, but I can't imagine that you're barred from using any if statements with React at all.

Comment: how and where are you calling `exportedVar()`?  (also, i'm almost certain that your build tool will complain about `import {App} from 'react';`; is that actual code?)

Comment: A common mistake: you'll need to use arrow functions to preserve `this`, because React does not do magic `this` rebinding (at least, not anymore. Probably for the best, too). Just use `onRow = {evt => this.onRowButton(evt)} ` etc. for your handlers, same as what you're already doing for `undo`, and you're good to go again. (also, you don't need parens around singleton arrow function arguments. But you *do* need them for empty argument lists, or multiple argument lists)

Comment: There isn't an issue with the "onRow" handler because that function is within the same file and is manually bound in the constructor.  The issue is that the "onUndoAction" is in a separate file and the behavior of "this" is behaving inconsistently

Answer (score 0):

You can use es6 method as updated your code below:

```
export const exportedVar = () => {
let stateCheck = this.state.stateCheckValue  //successfully pulls in the values of "this"

let thisState = this;  //in console, reads as thisState = App {props: {...}, state:{...} ...}

if (stateCheck == "foo") {


    let someVariable = thisState //Undefined!!

    //still undefined even if I set:
    // let thisState = this.state;


    ...
```

Comment: That unbinds "this", unfortunately.  I bound the function in the main function's constructor using the this.FunctionName = this.FunctionName.bind(this)  - so using an ES6 construction method isn't playing nice with the old es5 method of binding.